# Selenium grid is providing exception :PROXY_REREGISTRATION

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid2

I am now able to run selenium grid 2 successfully, thanks to you guys. Now I am facing a new issue, i.e. : Session [xxxxx] was terminated due to PROXY_REREGISTRATION

according to what i read it means that the node was disconnected and was retrying to connect to host, which failed.

but what I want is, how to tackle this exception. rather how to handle it>>???
Does anyone know something related to this one??

Comment: I believe the node has a registerCycle parameter that decides how frequently it reregisters. Can you try starting the node with a really high registerCycle parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue couple of days ago. Apparently I was using an old version of selenium-node image. I updated to latest version and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue and stumbled upon this question. Will it be okay if you let me know what approach you took to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, later I figured that for some reason the node was getting registered twice in my code so due to which PROXY_REREGISTRATION error was coming. After removing the duplicate node registration, this issue got resolved.